# Sequence of remainders of multiples

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am interested in the sequence of remainders of the integers $kp$ when divided by $q$, with $\gcd(p,q)=1$.

For instance, with $p=7,q=17$,

$$\color{blue}0,7,14,\color{blue}4,11,\color{blue}1,8,15,\color{blue}5,12,\color{blue}2,9,16,\color{blue}6,13,\color{blue}3,10\cdots$$
 and so on, with period $q$. The numbers highlighted in blue are those preceded by a smaller one (when the term has "overflown").

I would like to know if there is a closed-formula to tell where these numbers occur, i.e. how to efficiently determine the indexes $$0,3,5,8,10,13,15.$$

Comment: Indeed, that mustn't be far from the solution as it is asymptotically correct. But needs to be confirmed with other values. Mh, doesn't work with $5/17$.

Comment: @Peter: sorry, confusion in the indexing. I have found no counterexample so far.

Comment: @peter: I will try to confirm analytically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the formula

$$\frac{kq}{p}$$ for p|k and $$1+trunc(\frac{kq}{p})$$ otherwise does the job.

The two given examples calculated in PARI/GP :

```
? x=[];p=7;q=17;for(k=1,100,if(Mod(k,p)==0,x=concat(x,k*q/p));if(Mod(k,p)<>0,x=c
oncat(x,1+truncate(k*q/p))));y=[];for(k=1,x[length(x)],if(component(Mod(k*p,q),2
)<component(Mod((k-1)*p,q),2),y=concat(y,k)));print(x==y)
1
? x=[];p=5;q=17;for(k=1,100,if(Mod(k,p)==0,x=concat(x,k*q/p));if(Mod(k,p)<>0,x=c
oncat(x,1+truncate(k*q/p))));y=[];for(k=1,x[length(x)],if(component(Mod(k*p,q),2
)<component(Mod((k-1)*p,q),2),y=concat(y,k)));print(x==y)
1
?
```

I omitted the case $k=0$, but obviously the formula gives $0$ for $k=0$, which is true by default.

Comment: I still couldn't prove it, but I trust the formula.